# Manually populating a model that includes a collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to populate a model for a page in ASP.net Core using the file system. What I've got mostly works, but the MusicFile collection doesn't display correctly - all items show the MusicFiles that should be associated with the last item. I don't know if this is because previous items  are being overwritten as I populate the model, or if for some reason it's failing to access the correct collection in the View. I've tried using various types and various types of for loops to no avail. This is what I have currently:

Model:

```
public class MusicItem
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MusicFile> MusicFiles { get; set; }
}

public class MusicFile
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
}
```

Controller (simplified):

```
public IActionResult Files(string folder)
    {
        List<MusicItems> MusicList = new List<MusicItems>();
        List<MusicFile> musicFiles = new List<MusicFile>();
        MusicFile musicFile;
        ..
        foreach (string folderName in folders)
        {
            if (musicFiles.Count>0) { musicFiles.Clear(); }
            for each file in files
            {
            ...
            musicFile = new MusicFile { Display = display, Url = MakeVirtualPath(fileName) };
            musicFiles.Add(musicFile);
            }
        MusicList.Add(new MusicItems { Name = folderName, MusicFiles = musicFiles });

        }

    return View(MusicList);  
    }
```

View:

```
@model List<Web.Areas.Admin.Models.MusicItem>


@foreach (var Musicitem in Model)
{
    int id = 0;

        <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Musicitem.Name)</h3>


        @for (int i = 0; i < Musicitem.MusicFiles.Count; i++)
        {

            if (id != 0)
            {<span> |  </span>}
            <a href="@Musicitem.MusicFiles[i].Url">@Musicitem.MusicFiles[i].Display</a>
            id++;

        }

}
```

NB I've simplified the controller quite heavily - assume all variables are defined somewhere. The headings display correctly. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Try using a debugging tool to help yourself narrow down the general area where things are going awry. From there you can focus your attention on a small subset of code rather than the entire traversal path. Otherwise, one guess is as good as another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by this: `musicFiles.Clear();` and this `MusicFiles = musicFiles`. You are assigning the `musicFiles` variable which is a reference type in c# (List) to each `MusicItem`. All of them (music items) point to the same reference of the list, so when you call `Clear` everyone that holds a reference will "see" the changes. Similarly, when your loop ends and fills `musicFiles`, all `MusicItems` will have the same values, since they point to the same reference.

It's essentially how C# variables work, so it's good that you have an understanding of this. It's not too complicated, you just need some reading/practice to wrap your head around it.

I strongly suggest you read these two awesome articles written by Jon Skeet [References and Values](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html) and later [Parameter passing in C#](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html). In my opinion, his explanation is one of the best I've ever seen on this topic. It's succinct and clear. But make sure you get it because this is essential on how C# works and it will make your life much easier/better as a developer.

Solving your issue:

You can solve it by slightly changing your code to:

```
public IActionResult Files(string folder)
{
    List<MusicItems> MusicList = new List<MusicItems>();

    foreach (string folderName in folders)
    {
        // creates an item with an empty list of files
        var musicItem = new MusicItems { Name = folderName, MusicFiles = new List<MusicFile>() };

        foreach(var file in files)
        {
            // create the file
            musicFile = new MusicFile { Display = display, Url = MakeVirtualPath(fileName) };

            // add the file to the item, declared in the loop.
            musicItem.MusicFiles.Add(musicFile);
        }

        MusicList.Add(musicItem);
    }

    return View(MusicList);  
}
```